# Modeling Interest Rate Time Series

Tags: interest-rates

What is the right way to express the change in interest rate time series, if this time series contains both positive and negative rates?

Comment: Current rate minus previous rate?

Comment: how about proportional change? i am trying to estimate tail risk and am hoping to generate time series that follows normal distribution

Comment: Proportional changes don't make sense if rates can be zero or negative.

Comment: Yes, sir. Hence my question. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Use current rate minus previous rate.

Comment: Question is probably mistated. OP seems to want to know how to model interest rates as an appropriate stochastic process.

Comment: Actually i am trying to estimate tail risk (VaR) based on historical data. Ideally, I was hoping to use the parametric approach, based on the change in this time series. However, not sure what the best way to express the change is, given the limitations that I mentioned. Thanks everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approaches used to deal with negative interest rates are:

a) the normal (Bachelier) model or Brownian motion, where $dr_t = \sigma dW_t$; this makes changes independent from the level of the interest rate,

b) shifted lognormal (displaced diffusion) model, where, instead of the ordinary Geometric Brownian Motion $dr_t = r_t \sigma dW_t$, we have $dr_t = (r_t + h) \sigma dW_t$ with for example $h=2\%$ or any similar value accepted by convention or made to fit the data; this keeps changes somewhat proportional to the rate level, while allowing negative values up to $-h$.

You can also look at [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/modelling-with-negative-interest-rates) question, which has useful references.